# Javascript - Most efficient way to search thousand texts for thousands of words?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, search, text

the language itself is not that important, but I'd figure I'd stick with Javascript.

Essentially, I have thousands of "comments" each month and would like to have a naive happiness 'evaluation' by automation based on searching 10,000 words within those comments (average word count of each comment is 21 words, taking everything so far).

The way the formula works (borrowed from Hedonometer) -- is take the 'happiness' score of each word in the text (if found in the 10k list) and average it.

I'll test a few things and maybe edit back in the results here, but I'm not even sure where to begin. Seems like very heavy data lifting (Though only needs to be done once per comment of course) -- and maybe it's better suited to R or SQL (likely not), but not sure.

I believe this problem is sometimes referred to as 'bag of words' or 'term frequency saturation'.

Comment: "Most efficient" depends on a bunch of factors....

Comment: Yeah doing some reading and learned there is a hell of a lot of complexity in terms of rapid string search methods. Hmm. Maybe I'll some of the simpler methods on wikipedia and see if the processing time is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a hash table from your words like so (abbreviated) :

```
let wordRanks = {'hate':-100,'love':100,'ok':10};
```

Then have a string like this and split it into words.

```
let str = `I hate love it's just ok`;
let words = str.split(' ');
```

Then you can iterate through the words and get a score :

```
let commentScore = 0;
words.forEach(function(word){
  if(wordRanks[word]){
    commentScore += parseInt(wordRanks[word])
  }
});
console.log(commentScore); //should be 10
```

Using a hash table shouldn't be computationally expensive for the lookup. Should work, although you may have to split the words better to remove trailing punctuation, as I had a comma after love in my initial code and it gave the wrong result because there was no hash table match for 'love,'

Comment: Hmm very interesting. I'll try to test this out. The thing is, based on the Hedonometer journal paper, they didn't sum the word scores, they averaged them. So in your fictitious example, the average would be 3.33 (10/3) -- in practice, the word 'score' are from 1-10, so there are no negatives. Definitely will try this and see if it's feasible from a time perspective, thanks.

Comment: Cool, hopefully you should be able to adapt that approach to whatever your scoring system is as long as you understand the code behind the loop and the hash table.  If you're dealing with floating numbers though, the parseInt might be parseFloat as well.

Comment: Update on this approach: It works surprisingly faster than I expected. On a mediocre computer, it applies and scores the 10k list of words on 1000 21-avg-word-comments in under 9 seconds. Might not be the most optimized approach, but certainly works. Have about 2-3k comments a month, so that's about 18-27 seconds. Only 'inelegant' part is getting the word list in Javascript. The 10k list is static, so I just used some processing to put the HUGE list on one Javascript line, but wondering if there is a better method to maintain this list, thru SQL or another format. Thanks!

Comment: @user45867: Why not store the word list in a file and have your program load it at run time?

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely go with [Python's Natural Language Toolkit (NLTK)](http://www.nltk.org/) it comes with a set of functions that will make your life easier, like text frequencies, remove duplicates, remove of stop words, find synonyms, etc., the idea being reducing the size of your text as much as possible to do the sentiment analysis.

In a similar project my approach was:

1. Remove neutral words, pronouns, prepositions, determiners, names, etc.
2. Remove duplicates.
3. Check for word synonyms as I progressed into the text and remove them from the rest of the text.
4. Dynamically create a sentiment threshold score for a paragraph, so once it reached that score I'd stop working on that paragraph and move on to the next one, the same for the text in overall.

Hope this works!

Comment: Thanks - great guide on that site, too. Yeah I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel exactly. I'll give it a read through.

Comment: jus a note, in case you do something similar, if you remove synonyms or duplicates they should add to the score anyway, so if you remove the word "laughing" from a paragraph 6 times and do not count the six iterations you'd most probably have a wrong score for that specific paragraph. Also NLTK has a good set of tools for analyzing context, it's VERY useful, words like "cry" could signify sadness or anger, so context matters a lot.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate the methodology Hedonometer, just because it appears to be robust from their own internal testing. Yes, they count duplicates or triplicates accordlingly. They do not account for context. I'm not going for pinpoint accuracy of course (human evaluation can do that) - more of an initial pass thru score/ basic categorization. But yes, even this 'simple' model of averaging word happiness score - is hard to implement technically, at least for me right now.